# PuppetDB: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, puppet, puppetdb, puppet-agent

I'm attempting to use puppetdb on but I'm running into some issues.

I have a node called `puppet`. It is the master as well as where I've installed puppetdb. It's also a node that puppet manages.

When I run `puppet -t` on the puppet node I get:

```
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not retrieve facts for puppet.example.com: 
Failed to submit 'replace facts' command for puppet.example.com to PuppetDB at
puppet:8081: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate
B: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for
/CN=puppet.example.com]
```

I'm assuming that something is wrong w/ the SSL but I'm not sure what to change or where to look.

Comment: What process did you follow to set up PuppetDB's cert (step 3, A or B [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppetdb/latest/install_from_source.html#step-3-option-a-run-the-ssl-configuration-script))?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like problem with hostname on PuppetDB (master) server. Make sure that `hostname -f` outputs address that is resolvable from all node where `puppet agent` runs.

From the error log it seems that the hostname is just `puppet`:

```
Failed to submit 'replace facts' command for puppet.example.com to PuppetDB at
puppet:8081
```

Then move old certificates

- for **PuppetDB 2.x**:

  ```
  mv /etc/puppet/puppetdb/ssl/ /etc/puppet/puppetdb/ssl-old
  puppetdb-ssl-setup -f
  ```
- for **PuppetDB 3.x** and newer:

  ```
  mv /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/ssl/ /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/ssl-old
  puppetdb ssl-setup -f
  ```

Finally restart the service:

```
service puppetdb restart
```